# Why is my nested table rendering outside the table in DOM?

Tags: html, email, html-email

I am creating an email, and I have a main table and then nested tables inside of it. One of my tables is displaying outside the table on the DOM and I cannot figure out why.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title> *|SUBJECT|*</title>
    <style>
    .bodyContent{
        color:#505050;
        font-family:Helvetica;
        font-size:16px;
        line-height:150%;
        padding-top:20px;
        padding-right:20px;
        padding-bottom:20px;
        padding-left:20px;
        text-align:left;
    }
    .bodyContent a:link, .bodyContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .bodyContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
        color:#45B5DD;
        font-weight:normal;
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .bodyContent img{
        display:inline;
        height:auto;
        max-width:560px;
    }
    .header {
        max-height: 125px;
    }
    .mso-width{
        width: 100%;
    }

    a[href^=tel]{
        color:#ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        .ds-logo{
            display: block;
            float: none;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .header {
            padding: 10px 0;
        }
        .width-container {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        .phone-number{
            width: 120px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#f4f4f4; height:100% !important; width:100% !important; ">

    <!-- WRAPPER -->
    <!--[if mso]>
    <style>
    .width-container {
    display: inline;
    width: 600px !important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<table style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #f4f4f4; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <!-- Header -->
                <td class="header mso-width" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0; border-top: 0px solid #BBBBBB; max-width: 600px; width: 100% !important;" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" valign="top">

                    <table class="width-container" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; width: 300px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #000000; width: 100%">
                                <img class="ds-logo" src="http://example.com/emails/DS_White_Medium.png" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="width-container" align="left" bgcolor="#000000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 300px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff!important; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 18px; height: 100%; line-height: 125%; text-align: right; letter-spacing: .0em; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; text-decoration: none" width="100%">
                                <div class="phone-number">
                                    866.111.1111
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <!-- End Header -->

            </table>
            <!-- Hero Image -->
            <table style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #f4f4f4; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0; border-top: 0px solid #BBBBBB; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;" align="center" valign="top">
                        <img alt="" src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/hero.jpg" style="max-width: 600px" width="100%"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <!-- End Hero -->

            <!-- Content -->
            <table class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="bodyContent" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 40px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: left;" valign="top">{{lead.First Name:default=Friend}}, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- End Content -->

            <!-- Icon Points -->
            <table class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <table align="left" class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <img src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/icon-1.png" alt="" /><br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                Mobile optimization and a fully web-based platform enables cross-browser, cross-platform functionality
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table align="left" class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <img src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/icon-2.png" alt="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                Custom queues provide structured, user-tailored workflow processes
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <table align="left" class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <img src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/icon-1.png" alt="" /><br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                Mobile optimization and a fully web-based platform enables cross-browser, cross-platform functionality
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table align="left" class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <img src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/icon-2.png" alt="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                Custom queues provide structured, user-tailored workflow processes
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- End Icon Points -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/9511L1qb/

Comment: I'd bet it is because of an error that https://validator.w3.org/nu/ reports.

Comment: The validator shows 82 errors, most of which are deprecated functions.

Comment: This is an email so it has to include a lot of those for older clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a td tag around the offending tables.

Line 122 and 147 (the 'ICON POINTS' module) need a `<td>` and `</td>`.

You also have a `<tr>` tag missing in your header module

Answer (score 0):

Why the table frenzy? A lot of people have had a lot of trouble with it, it is simply bad design. Use a DIV element to space out your page, use a TABLE element when you want to display a table. I've stripped down your code and created a working example, see the huge increase in readability?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title> *|SUBJECT|*</title>
    <style>
    .bodyContent{
        color:#505050;
        font-family:Helvetica;
        font-size:16px;
        line-height:150%;
        padding-top:20px;
        padding-right:20px;
        padding-bottom:20px;
        padding-left:20px;
        text-align:left;
    }
    .bodyContent a:link, .bodyContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .bodyContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
        color:#45B5DD;
        font-weight:normal;
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .bodyContent img{
        display:inline;
        height:auto;
        max-width:560px;
    }
    .header {
        max-height: 125px;
    }
    .mso-width{
        width: 100%;
    }

    a[href^=tel]{
        color:#ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        .ds-logo{
            display: block;
            float: none;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .header {
            padding: 10px 0;
        }
        .width-container {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        .phone-number{
            width: 120px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- WRAPPER -->
    <!--[if mso]>
        <style>
            .width-container {
            display: inline;
            width: 600px !important;
        }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <div style="background-color: #ffffff; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div style="background-color: #000000;">
            <img class="ds-logo" style="float: left; margin: 10px 0 0 10px;" src="http://example.com/emails/DS_White_Medium.png" />
            <div class="phone-number" style = "color: white; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 18px; text-align: right; letter-spacing: .0em; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; text-decoration: none">
                866.111.1111
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent" style="padding: 40px 30px; text-align: center;">
            <div style="width: 100%;">
                <img alt="" src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/hero.jpg" style="max-width: 600px; margin: 10px auto;" width="100%"/>
                <p style="text-align: left;">{{lead.First Name:default=Friend}}, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
                reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
                deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 100%; min-height: 300px;">
                <div class="leftblock" style="width: 40%; float: left; clear: left;">
                    <img src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/icon-1.png" alt="" />
                    <p style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; text-align: left;">Mobile optimization and a fully web-based platform enables cross-browser, cross-platform functionality</p>
                </div>
                <div class="rightblock" style="width: 40%; float: left; margin-left: 10%;">
                    <img src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/icon-2.png" alt="" />
                    <p style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; text-align: left;">Custom queues provide structured, user-tailored workflow processes</p>
                </div>
                <div class="leftblock" style="width: 40%; float: left; clear: left;">
                    <img src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/icon-1.png" alt="" />
                    <p style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; text-align: left;">Mobile optimization and a fully web-based platform enables cross-browser, cross-platform functionality</p>
                </div>
                <div class="rightblock" style="width: 40%; float: left; margin-left: 10%;">
                    <img src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/icon-2.png" alt="" />
                    <p style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; text-align: left;">Custom queues provide structured, user-tailored workflow processes</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: here is a workaround in case you really need to use the table structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title> *|SUBJECT|*</title>
    <style>
    .bodyContent{
        color:#505050;
        font-family:Helvetica;
        font-size:16px;
        line-height:150%;
        padding-top:20px;
        padding-right:20px;
        padding-bottom:20px;
        padding-left:20px;
        text-align:left;
    }
    .bodyContent a:link, .bodyContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .bodyContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
        color:#45B5DD;
        font-weight:normal;
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .bodyContent img{
        display:inline;
        height:auto;
        max-width:560px;
    }
    .header {
        max-height: 125px;
    }
    .mso-width{
        width: 100%;
    }

    a[href^=tel]{
        color:#ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        .ds-logo{
            display: block;
            float: none;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .header {
            padding: 10px 0;
        }
        .width-container {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        .phone-number{
            width: 120px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#f4f4f4; height:100% !important; width:100% !important; ">

    <!-- WRAPPER -->
    <!--[if mso]>
    <style>
    .width-container {
    display: inline;
    width: 600px !important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<table style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #f4f4f4; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <!-- Header -->
                <td class="header mso-width" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0; border-top: 0px solid #BBBBBB; max-width: 600px; width: 100% !important;" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" valign="top">

                    <table class="width-container" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; width: 300px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #000000; width: 100%">
                                <img class="ds-logo" src="http://example.com/emails/DS_White_Medium.png" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="width-container" align="left" bgcolor="#000000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 300px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff!important; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 18px; height: 100%; line-height: 125%; text-align: right; letter-spacing: .0em; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; text-decoration: none" width="100%">
                                <div class="phone-number">
                                    866.111.1111
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <!-- End Header -->

            </table>
            <!-- Hero Image -->
            <table style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #f4f4f4; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; margin: 0; border-top: 0px solid #BBBBBB; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;" align="center" valign="top">
                        <img alt="" src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/hero.jpg" style="max-width: 600px" width="100%"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <!-- End Hero -->

            <!-- Content -->
            <table class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="bodyContent" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 40px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: left;" valign="top">{{lead.First Name:default=Friend}}, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- End Content -->
            <!-- End Icon Points -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <table style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>    
            <!-- Icon Points -->
            <table class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <table align="left" class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <img src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/icon-1.png" alt="" /><br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                Mobile optimization and a fully web-based platform enables cross-browser, cross-platform functionality
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table align="left" class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <img src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/icon-2.png" alt="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                Custom queues provide structured, user-tailored workflow processes
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <table align="left" class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <img src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/icon-1.png" alt="" /><br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                Mobile optimization and a fully web-based platform enables cross-browser, cross-platform functionality
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table align="left" class="width-container" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <img src="http://example.com/emails/independent/11082016/icon-2.png" alt="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                Custom queues provide structured, user-tailored workflow processes
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- End Icon Points -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

The result can also be seen on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k3pykzLy/

Comment: Outlook can have a tough time rendering div's properly, so not advised to use them. We're better off sticking with our tables for the time being

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. I'll update my original answer to get you forward, got it working.